# Symfony2 not respecting my session lifetime setting

Tags: symfony

I have my app set, in `app/config/config.yml`, to have a session lifetime of one year:

```
framework:
    session:
        default_locale: %locale%
        lifetime:       31536000
        auto_start:     true
```

However, my users are getting booted after about an *hour* of inactivity, which is of course less than a year. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: As of symfony2.4, it's `cookie_lifetime` instead of `lifetime`. In case you stumbled across this question if you were wondering: How do I set the session lifetime in symfony2. Like me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the culprit was `gc_maxlifetime` in php.ini being set to only 1440 seconds. A little more info here: [symfony2 session lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933774/symfony2-session-live-time)