# OrangeHRM auto logout issue

Tags: php, orangehrm, symfony-1.2

I'm facing auto logout issue with OrangeHRM built with `Symfony 1.2.4`

**What I have Tried?**

1. I have tried to allocate max time to SESSIONS via `php.ini` and `.htaccess`
2. Tried after commenting following code of file `/symfony/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/user/sfBasicSecurityUser.class.php`

   ```
   public function initialize(sfEventDispatcher $dispatcher, sfStorage $storage, $options = array())
   {
   // initialize parent
   parent::initialize($dispatcher, $storage, $options);

   if (!array_key_exists('timeout', $this->options))
   {
     $this->options['timeout'] = 86400;
     //$this->options['timeout'] = 1800;
   }


   $this->options['timeout'] = 86400;
   //$this->options['timeout'] = 2 * 24 * 60 * 60;

   // force the max lifetime for session garbage collector to be greater than timeout
   /*if (ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime') < $this->options['timeout'])
   {
     ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->options['timeout']);
   }*/
   ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->options['timeout']);

   // read data from storage
   $this->authenticated = $storage->read(self::AUTH_NAMESPACE);
   $this->credentials   = $storage->read(self::CREDENTIAL_NAMESPACE);
   $this->lastRequest   = $storage->read(self::LAST_REQUEST_NAMESPACE);

   if (null === $this->authenticated)
   {
     $this->authenticated = false;
     $this->credentials   = array();
   }
   else
   {
     // Automatic logout logged in user if no request within timeout parameter seconds
     $timeout = $this->options['timeout'];
     if (false !== $timeout && null !== $this->lastRequest && time() - $this->lastRequest >= $timeout)
     {
       if ($this->options['logging'])
       {
         $this->dispatcher->notify(new sfEvent($this, 'application.log', array('Automatic user logout due to timeout')));
       }

       $this->setTimedOut();
       $this->setAuthenticated(false);
     }
   }

   $this->lastRequest = time();
   ```

   }
3. Tried to set `$_SESSION['symfony/user/sfUser/lastRequest']` manually.
4. Tried to remain active via sending get request via `AJAX`.
5. Tried to increase session time from `YML` setting file located in `.../symfony/apps/orangehrm/config/factories.yml`

   ```
   all:
     routing:
       class: sfPatternRouting
       param:
         generate_shortest_url:            true
         extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
     storage:
       class: sfSessionStorage
       param:
         session_name: PHPSESSID
         session_cache_limiter: nocache
     user:
        class: myUser
        param:
          timeout:         86000
          logging:         %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
          use_flash:       true
          default_culture: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%
   ```

**End Result**

All of above techniques failed.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not touch files in the vendor directory !

The proper way to modify session lifetime in a symfony application is through the config.yml file. [See this question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933774/symfony2-session-lifetime).

Comment: Hello, thank you for response. I have tried your provided solution but still facing the issue.

Comment: My symfony version is `1.2.4`

Answer (score 0):

Even though this is a bit late, this will help you to extend the session timeout value. This setting is located in `.../symfony/apps/orangehrm/config/factories.yml` file.

There you will see the below setting,

```
all:
  routing:
    class: ohrmPatternRouting
    param:
      generate_shortest_url:            true
      extra_parameters_as_query_string: true
  storage:
    class: sfSessionStorage
    param:
      session_name: PHPSESSID
      session_cookie_secure: true
      session_cache_limiter: nocache
  user:
     class: myUser
     param:
       timeout:         1800 #change this value to change the session timeout interval
       logging:         %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
       use_flash:       true
       default_culture: %SF_DEFAULT_CULTURE%
```

The relevant value you should change is `timeout` parameter. Default value is 1800 seconds (30mins). If you are in the development environment, execute symfony clear cache command (in a terminal go inside the `symfony` folder and execute `./symfony cc`) to get it working. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for response. I already have tried this one but failed. Please see my update answer again.