# Symfony user session

Tags: symfony, session

I'm working with Symfony3.

On the web site, user can login to the system.

Problem: Users session lifetime should equal 7 days, after that logout him! How can I implement this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [symfony2 session lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933774/symfony2-session-lifetime)

Answer (score 0):

[From the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html#session-lifetime)

> PHP will only issue a cookie once. The client is expected to store that cookie for the entire lifetime. A new cookie will only be issued when the session is destroyed, the browser cookie is deleted, or the session ID is regenerated using the migrate() or invalidate() methods of the Session class.
>
> The initial cookie lifetime can be set by configuring NativeSessionStorage using the setOptions(array('cookie_lifetime' => 1234)) method.

In a real world example.  This would be in your config.yml.

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 1234
```

Comment: Yes, before send to production. And on server, after several hours, users logout. This is problem.

Comment: You need to implement something like remember_me. It is a good approach. Look FosUserBundle as the example.